# Can I run Masstransit with Kafka and InMemory transport as IPC?

Tags: apache-kafka, masstransit

Can I use MassTransit with Kafka rider and InMemory transport as a communication mechanism between the processes? Or the only option here is to use RabbitMq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka is neither designed nor intended to be used for IPC (inter-process communication). Kafka use cases are event streaming and data distribution/replication – use cases that are unidirectional architecturally.

I would not use Kafka for request/response or other dispatch-style command/event message patterns.

> Unfortunately, this is opinion-based and your question isn't entirely clear as to your requirements. But based on what little information is available, a message broker is more suitable since you mentioned IPC.

Comment: Yeah, my specific use case is asynchronous communication between processes: publishing events to potentially many recipients

Comment: One-way publishing of events to many consumers is where Kafka is great. Once that becomes a chatty two-way conversation, Kafka starts to struggle.